# Magento 1.7 overriding class

Tags: php, magento, overriding

I am trying to override the magento class

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
```

I have created a director and file local/myModules/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php and its code is.

```
include_once("Mage/Adminhtml/controller/Sales/Invoice.php");


class myModules_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice
{
    public function printAction()
   {
    echo "child class";exit;
    if ($invoiceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id')) {
        if ($invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoiceId)) {
            $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
                '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->_forward('noRoute');
    }
  }
}
```

And local/myModules/Adminhtml/config.xml is

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
<modules>
    <myModules_Adminhtml>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </myModules_Adminhtml>
</modules>


<global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                  <sales_order_view>myModules_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>

<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml> 
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <modules> 
                        <myModules_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">myModules_Adminhtml</myModules_Adminhtml>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

In the browser i have the url

```
/index.php/admin/sales_order_invoice/print/invoice_id/49191/
```

But it does not display "child class";

Actually I want to override the invoice print functionality. What in XML I am missing?

Comment: Did u flush the cache? Also it might be an acl (permissions) issue

Comment: You can't rewrite controller using `<rewrite>` directive, especially placed in `global/blocks`. Also, you should name your modules using CamelCase notation, otherwise class might be not loaded by autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

1) 'myModules' should be `MyModules`

2) Since you are using `<myModules_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">`

Replace

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
```

With

```
include_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml') . DS . 'Sales' . DS . 'InvoiceController.php';

class MyModules_Adminhtml_Sales_InvoiceController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_InvoiceController{
    ...
}
```

Read more @

[The Basics Of Creating A Magento Module](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/)

[How to overload a controller](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller)

[Magento: Overriding Core Files (Blocks, Models, Resources, Controllers)](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/)

Comment: I presume `Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml')` will point to `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/`. This is wrong for `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice` - the correct path is `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/`. You referred to a different file (`Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_InvoiceController` vs `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice`).